# What is the advantage of using the MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Any added advantage of using the MongoDB Atlas compared to having the DB on a local server ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a really simple answer.

Managing,securing and maintaining a DB can be alot of work. Work that you need at least someone specialized doing. MongoAtlas helps you to do that so that you can concentrate on your app and not on handling the database.

Here is [an article](https://medium.com/@nparsons08/mongodb-atlas-technical-overview-benefits-9e4cff27a75e) that explains it more in depth.